# Logic to validate data and removing noise rows

Tags: r, validation, dplyr, noise-reduction

I have a big dataset of about 4 Milion rows.
the columns are

1. Idx - dog serial number
2. date - date of event YYYY-MM-DD ( 2016 till 2021)
3. Is_sterilized  - 1 if the dog was sterilized and 0 if not sterilized.

each dog can appear many times in a year,
It can appear in 2016 and 2020 but not in 2017-2019.

I want to count how many dogs were sterilized each year, meaning, if a dog change from Is_serilized==0 to Is_sterilized ==1 in a year I count it as sterilized that year, the first year it appears sterilized counted as his year fo sterilization.

The issue is that my database is not clean and for some dogs goes from **sterilized** to **not sterilized**, this can not happen since sterilization is one-way ticket surgery.

It can happen that a dog appears sterilized, 3 years consecutive and then one year by mistake unsterilized and then sterilized for 2 years.

What I'm asking is if there is a logic that I can estimate/count how many dogs having the **wrong direction**.
And if so, how can I deduce those dogs from my dataset?

In the example data, Idx = A and C make sense but B and D does not make senese

```
df_test <- data.frame(Idx=c( 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B','A', 'A', 'C',  'C', 'D','D','D','D','D','D','C', 'C','A'  ),
                      YEAR_date=as.Date(c("2016-01-01","2016-01-29","2017-01-01","2016-05-01","2016-05-06","2016-05-01","2016-03-03","2016-04-22","2018-05-05", "2017-02-01"," 2021-11-12"," 2019-09-13"," 2019-11-12"," 2019-08-17", "2011-09-01"," 2011-07-05","2021-01-05")),
                     Is_sterilized =c(0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1)
)

df_test[,c( "Idx" ,"YEAR_date",  "Is_sterilized")]  %>% arrange(Idx ,YEAR_date      )
   Idx  YEAR_date Is_sterilized
1    A 2016-01-01             0
2    A 2016-05-01             1
3    A 2016-05-06             1
4    A 2021-01-05             1
5    B 2016-01-29             1
6    B 2016-05-01             1
7    B 2017-01-01             0
8    C 2011-07-05             1
9    C 2011-09-01             1
10   C 2016-03-03             1
11   C 2016-04-22             1
12   D 2017-02-01             1
13   D 2018-05-05             1
14   D 2019-08-17             1
15   D 2019-09-13             1
16   D 2019-11-12             0
17   D 2021-11-12             0
```

I have more columns is if you thing anything else is relevant please write and I'll check I have it.

Any hint idea anything will be helpul

Thanks You in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here's some `dplyr` code to identify instances where a dog's sterilization went from 1 to zero:

```
library(dplyr)
df_test %>%
  group_by(Idx) %>%
  mutate(change = Is_sterilized-lag(Is_sterilized, default = 0)) %>%
  filter(change == -1) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Idx   YEAR_date  Is_sterilized change
  <chr> <date>             <dbl>  <dbl>
1 B     2017-01-01             0     -1
2 D     2021-11-12             0     -1
3 D     2019-11-12             0     -1
```

If you want to count the number of dogs in that list, add `%>% count(Idx)` at the end.

```
df_test %>%
  group_by(Idx) %>%
  mutate(change = Is_sterilized-lag(Is_sterilized, default = 0)) %>%
  filter(change == -1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  count(Idx, name = "times_desterilized")

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Idx   times_desterilized
  <chr>              <int>
1 B                      1
2 D                      2
```